# how to specify image size in pixels

Tags: html

Quick question about specifying the size of images in pixels:

```
<img src="/logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="200px" height="120px" />
```

or

```
<img src="/logo.jpg" alt="logo" width="200" height="120" />
```

I've been always putting in the px but recently noticed that very few people do this. Am I better off leaving that out? Does it matter one way or the other?

Comment: The size of an image element are numbers, no "px" or other measure abreviation. Yo can use px or other in CSS not in HTML

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, you do not add the `px` label to width/height attribute values on the `img` tag itself, and I believe (though could be wrong) it's because pixels are used regardless. In CSS, however, one may use different units to specify width and height, therefore it is appropriate to add the label when using CSS.

Comment: Pixels are used unless you specify it as percentage :)

Answer (score 2):

Could not find any information that verifies this but I would use integers without a unit (if not percentage) in HTML and use "px" in CSS, except for zero values where it´s more correct to leave out the unit.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property

Comment: It seems that this is the approach taken by the firefox web validator, it flags the use of px as an error

Answer (score 1):

I usually leave it out. As not often is the case I use `<img>` elements. But, it is better practice to place the width and height in the `<img>` tag so the browser doesn't have to calculate these dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Use css to consider the the size of the image:

CSS:

```
.logo {
width: 200px;
height: 120px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="/logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would continue to specify the size in pixels. You probably don't need to, but I think you're supposed to according to web standards. Specifying the size in pixels is definitely not going to hurt your code, so leave it there.

Comment: I don´t think it´s a web standard to include the "px" in HTML size attribures. Haven´t found any greater evidence for this yet though but I´ll get back if I do :P

Comment: James, adding `px` unit will make Outlook (and possibly other applications) scale the images as if no height/width was specified, so it *does* hurt. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36485410/html-signature-is-resizing-only-some-images-in-outlook?noredirect=1#comment60722825_36485410